# Correct method of creating custom authentication using username and password in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, plugins, activemq-classic

I have several installations of ActiveMQ 5.10 that I would like to secure.  The first step is to validate the client id, username, and password to against a table in a database.  This list will (hopefully) change often so it must remain dynamic.

I located several examples for developing an extended BrokerFilter and it appears to work correctly - I can tell by logging that I added.  The problem is that there is some other part of ActiveMQ that takes the username and password and attempts to authenticate.  I believe that since no other authentication is enabled, it fails with the message:  User name or password is invalid.

So either I implemented the code in the wrong location or there is something missing from my code to tell ActiveMQ that the authentication has been performed and the connection should be allowed.

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 0):

The question was, is implementing BrokerFilter the correct method for authenticating a connection or is there a better way to accomplish that task? If it is the best way, what might trip one up when doing this? Having said that, I found the LoginModule class which is more suited to this task.